# How does F# pipeline operator work

Tags: f#, pipeline

have a code:

```
 //e = 1/2*Sum((yi -di)^2)
    let error y d =
        let map = 
            Array.map2 (fun y d -> (y - d) ** 2.0) y d
        let sum = 
            Array.sum map
        (sum / 2.0)

    let error2 y d =
        Array.map2 (fun y d -> (y - d) ** 2.0) y d
        |> Array.sum
        |> (/) 2.0
```

as i understood those functions should produce the same results, but there are a big difference in the results. Can anyone explain this?

p.s. Simplified example:

```
let test = [|1..10|]
    let res = test
                |> Array.sum
                |> (/) 5
```

i expect test = 11 (sum(1..10) = 55 and then 55 / 5) but after Array.sum pipeline is not working as i want(as result test = 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` operator does not work the way you have assumed.  You just need to be a bit more explicit and change the last line in error2 to

```
fun t -> t/2.0
```

and then it should all work.

The answers being out by a factor of 4 was the giveaway here.

**EDIT:** To understand what happens with `/` here consider what happens when you expand out `|>`

The following are all equivalent

```
a |> (/) b
((/) b) a //by removing |>
a / b     //what happens when / is reinterpreted as a function
```

Comment: would you like to say it will be interpreted as `b/a` instead of `a/b`?

Comment: last line should be "b / a" imo. i'm sure |> (op) x is a huge source for bugs in f# code ;)

Answer (score 6):

another alternative is to use the reverse pipe operator (<|) so that partial application of (/) is done with arguments in correct order:

```
let error2 y d =
    Array.map2 (fun y d -> (y - d) ** 2.0) y d
    |> Array.sum
    |> (/) <| 2.0
```

Edit: see if this helps clarify

```
x/y = (/) x y = y |> (/) x = x |> (/) <| y
```

All those are equivalent. The pipe operators are defined as:

```
(|>) x f = f x
(<|) f x = f x
```

where f is a function and x is some value. The reverse pipe doesn't look like it does much but it can help clean up some code in certain situations.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to misunderstand order of arguments in infix functions.

You can expand the point-free form as follows:

```
x |> (/) 5
<=> (/) 5 x
<=> 5 / x
```

So it's is the reverse of what you expect. It only works fine for commutative functions like `(+)`, `(*)`, etc. If you're keen on point-free style, the `flip` function is helpful to be used with `|>`:

```
let inline flip f x y = f y x

let error2 y d =
    Array.map2 (fun y d -> (y - d) ** 2.0) y d
    |> Array.sum
    |> flip (/) 2.0
```